# xUnit Check if Attribut(es) exist on a Class or Method

Tags: c#, xunit, xunit.net

Is there a way with xUnit to test that a method has specific attributes on it?

```
[HttpGet]
[SwaggerOperation(OperationId = "blah", Summary = "blah", Description = "blah")]
[ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
public async Task<ActionResult<IList<string>>> GetSomething
(
    [Required, FromRoute(Name = "blah")] Guid aGuid,
)
{}
```

I would like to be able to test that `[HttpGet]` and all of the other attributes exist on the `GetSomething` method. Also, if possible would like to check that the `[Required]` attribute is on the method parameter `aGuid`

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226161/test-if-a-class-has-an-attribute and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55419864/c-sharp-webapi-how-to-unit-test-if-a-controller-action-is-decorated-with-an-auth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access attributes and their data by using reflection:
[Accessing Attributes by Using Reflection (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/accessing-attributes-by-using-reflection)
[Retrieving Information Stored in Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/attributes/retrieving-information-stored-in-attributes)

But I would suggest to use [FluentAssertions](https://fluentassertions.com/documentation/) library, which provide same approach in a fluently readable way.

```
[Fact]
public void GetAll_ShouldBeDecoratedWithHttpGetAttribute()
{
    var getSomething = nameof(_controller.GetSomething);
    typeof(MyController).GetTypeInfo()
        .GetMethod(getSomething)
        .Should()
        .BeDecoratedWith<HttpGetAttribute>();
}
```